# Display minibuffer on all frames

Tags: frames, minibuffer

The minibuffer is only displayed on the active window's frame.

For instance, the following creates three frames.  The minibuffer shows on the first frame (the initial frame created and, thus, the active frame).  The two additional frames do not display the minibuffer.  I would expect the minibuffer to appear on all three frames.

```sh
emacs -q --eval "(progn (make-frame) (make-frame) (execute-extended-command nil))"
```

I am aware of packages that display the minibuffer as a separate frame itself, but of no option to display the minibuffer on each frame.

How might I display the minibuffer within each frame?

Comment: I think you're asking to show the minibuffer prompt, and your input as you type it, in each frame. Yes, what you wrote is sufficient: "display the minibuffer". But because many users confuse the echo area with the minibuffer it might be clearer if you added such info. The minibuffer is present in each frame, but it is shown only for the frame that has the input focus.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to satisfy your request. But perhaps someone will prove me wrong and give you the answer.

Comment: "many users confuse the echo area with the minibuffer" - I am one such user!  I suspect I would also like the echo area to display on each frame.  However, I imagine that's a separate question since I assume the echo area and minibuffer implementations are separate.  Are those implemented in C?  I couldn't locate their definitions.